# Why some user functions don't get recognised by bash?

Tags: command-line, bash

I can define a function like:

`myfunction () { ls -R "$1" ; }`

And then

`myfunction .`

just works.

But if I do

```
echo "myfunction ." | sh
echo "myfunction ." | bash
```

the messages are:

```
sh: myfunction: not found  
bash: line 1: myfunction: command not found
```

Why? And how can I call a function that comes from a string if not by piping it to sh or bash?

I know there is this command `source`, but I am confused of when I should use `source` and when `sh` or `bash`. Also, I cannot pipe through `source`. To add to confusion, there is this command `.` that seems to have nothing to do with the "." that means "current directory".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A function definition only has an effect in the current instance of bash. When you write

```
echo "myfunction ." | bash
```

you run another instance of bash. You would need to define the function in that other instance.

If you have a string that contains a function name and arguments (quoted, if necessary), or more generally any string that contains some shell source code that you want to execute, use the `eval` builtin.

```
my_snippet='myfunction .'
eval "$my_snippet"
```

If you define functions in your `.bashrc`, they are only available in interactive shells, not in scripts.

The `.` command is (almost) equivalent to `source`, and has nothing to do with `.` meaning the current directory.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using `eval`, you can `export` your function so it is inherited by subshells:

```
myfunction () { ls -R "$1" ; }
export -f myfunction
```

And then

```
echo "myfunction ." | bash
```

just works.

`echo "myfunction ." | sh` probably won't still, unless your /bin/sh is a symlink to bash.

Comment: Only works in bash, but thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

<s>`bash` and `sh` expect their argument to be an executable file, not a string.</s>

You can execute the contents of a string with

```
eval "myfunction ."
```

When you run a program through the shell, it will normally invoke a new instance of `bash` (or `sh`, `csh`, `zsh`, etc. as appropriate), inherit all the original shell's settings, and run itself in the new shell. This allows you to temporarily set variables or change settings without interfering with your environment.

`source`ing a command will make it run it your current shell, so any changes it makes to the environment will persist when the command exits. `.` is a synonym for `source`.

In most circumstances, a script will specify what shell it is meant to run in (with `#!/bin/bash` in its first line, for example), and it isn't necessary for you to call bash explicitly.

Comment: A command like `echo "myfunction ." | bash` is not passing `myfunction .` to `bash` as a command-line argument. It's running bash and [piping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) it the text `myfunction .` in lieu of [standard input](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams). That's totally different.

Comment: You're completely right. Thanks for the reminder.